# Woocommerce - looping product images

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

How can I loop the product images as a list?

Apparently, Woocommerce has two php files for this. One is for the featured product, and one is for the product thumbnails (`product-image.php` & `product-thumbnails.php`).
I'd like to put them on a single php file and loop the product images and make them appear in a `li` tag.

Comment: Are you developing a plugin? Just saw, that you filed it under [tag:plugin-development], but the question sounds like customizing a theme.

Answer (score 1):

You're completely on the right track - have you had a look at those files? All the info is in there.

The images are wrapped in a `<div>` within `product-image.php` which you would change to a `<ul>`. Then wrap the featured image in a `<li>`. Then you would just wrap the thumbs within an `<li>` in `product-thumbnails.php` and that would be finito.